# How to create prompt page driven variable view in Cognos 8.2

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-8

I am using Cognos 8.2 to create a report with a prompt page.  I am trying to create a prompt page that allows the user to choose what type of item they want to see, and then the workers assigned.

Example: Show me the workers working on projects of type 'A' and that would trigger a list of workers to be displayed who are currently working on projects of type 'A' and then the user could choose a worker/workers from the list to be displayed in the report.

I am trying to use javascript in the html item, but I have never worked with javascript before, and I am having little luck.  I dont know if it is even possible or not to pass a variable to another item on the prompt page.  Any ideas or examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the type "A" portion part of your database?

Comment: @melee no the "type" is not in our database. It would be a list that I would have to hard code.

Answer (score 0):

Bring your worker names into a data item (eg [People]) - then, create another data item with a case statement:

```
CASE
WHEN ([People] in ('John','Jessica','Jane','Jeff'))
THEN ('Group J')
WHEN ([People] in ('Adam', 'Alex', 'Anne'))
THEN ('Group A')
ELSE 'No Group'
END
```

Name this data item "Group"

Then create a filter on the query: `[Group] = ?Group Prompt?`

Then you should be able to input 'Group A' and get only those from Group A.

Comment: This works fine, but I needed to have the user be able to choose the group then have the worker's names appear and the user have the ability to choose one or more of the worker names.  I dont know if this possible.

Comment: Then you need to define drill down options on the user name, if I understand correctly.

Comment: the thing is....using your example above I want to have two list one showing "group type" and based on users selection of group type that would then populate the list of people that the user could choose from.  The people list would populate based on the users choice from the "group type" list.